# Regular expression for blank lines and lines with only one character

Tags: c#, regex

I'am searching for pattern for replace regular expression for C# which would delete all blank lines from txt files and also lines where is only one character which is '*'. This character has leading TAB's.

Help me with right pattern to remove those lines from below text:

```
Bla bla bla 


Bla bla bla
                  *
Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla
```

Expectation:

```
Bla bla bla 
Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla
```

Comment: `^\s*\*?$` seems to be what you're looking for (in multiline mode), see a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/hJ8gV4/1

Comment: Almost. Second and thirs row has leading space.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment, you could use the following regex:

```
^\s*\*?$\R
# look for whitespaces at the beginning of the line/string
# look for the star literally right at the end
# match a newline character
# anchor the expression to the beginning and end
```

In multi-line mode, you'd then need to replace all occurences with an empty string, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hJ8gV4/1).

Comment: Almost. Second and thirs row has leading space.